# django social share button icons

Tags: html, css, django, django-templates

I'm trying to add the functionality to share a workout post to social media, and found that the django-social-share package is the best.

Everything works, but I'm curious how to add an icon over the link, as it currently looks like

```
Post to Facebook!
```

which is very bland. I've seen examples of adding CSS, but since the package works like

```
{% post_to_facebook object_or_url "Post to Facebook!" %}
```

I'm not sure how you could target that with CSS. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can override all `templates` and then add `icon` or change the `style`..

All templates Dir. **must** be in this order :

```
Templates
  |__ django_social_share
       |__ templatetags
             |__ post_to_facebook.html
             |__ post_to_twitter.html
             |__ send_email.html
             |__ ......
             |__ ADD ALL TEMPLATES
```

For Ex.
**post_to_facebook.html:**

```
<div class="facebook-this">                
    <a href="{{ facebook_url }}" class="{{ link_class }}" target="_blank"><i class="fa fa-facebook-square" aria-hidden="true"></i> Post to Facebook!</a>
</div>
```

[See All Templates Here...](https://github.com/fcurella/django-social-share/tree/master/django_social_share/templates/django_social_share/templatetags)

Comment: I'm a little confused. So I would create a new templates folder inside the project, then follow the structure and just create new html files for the social links that I want icons to?

Comment: @timrockx yes, first create template folder and then register(inside TEMPLATES/Dir) it in settings.py then create template inside it..But remember file/folder structure and file name must be same [as this..](https://github.com/fcurella/django-social-share/tree/master/django_social_share/templates/django_social_share/templatetags)